# Question mischaracterized as off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

A while back I posted a question about *GoldenEye* glitching out when you press down on a chip in the N64 controller. The question was closed for being off-topic, presumably because it was about a glitch in a specific game which is better suited to Arqade. The trouble is, my confusion was why pressing down on an exposed chip would have any effect at all on the game, let alone triggering abnormal behavior.

In my opinion, this is very clearly a hardware related question, that would make more sense here than Arqade.

I didn't vote to reopen because I haven't edited it, but I feel that it was incorrectly closed.

[What is the cause of Trent's circuit board strategy?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12622/what-is-the-cause-of-trents-circuit-board-strategy)

Answer (score 4):

I voted to reopen.  I agree this is a very topical question.

My impression is that we have a contingent of users (some of them pretty vocal) that tend to dismiss anything even tangentially emulator- or game-related as off-topic, and prefer to turf it off to Arqade.  Some of this, I imagine, may be out of some quixotic pursuit of purity (‘retroCOMPUTING not retroGAMING’ and ‘well, the emulator is modern, supported software, isn’t it? huh? huh? stop hitting yourself!’), or it may be because their attitude to those topics has been soured by persistent [troll activity](/q/943/).  The former I regard as pretty misguided (as long as the tech is old enough and we consider its computing aspects, as opposed to the narrative content, it’s fine in my book), and though I am more sympathetic towards the latter, I still don’t think it wise to throw out the baby with the bathwater.  However, I invite anyone to make their case otherwise.

Comment: While amusing, it's _probably_ best not to make a straw argument of a position held by “a contingent of users” – even if you're keeping it generic. It could reasonably be seen as trolling.